# generate a birthday date randomly in c

Tags: c, date, random

```
int nombreAlea(int min, int max){
    return (rand()%(max-min+1) + min);
}

int main () {
    srand(time(0));
    int annee=nombreAlea(1940,2003),mois=nombreAlea(1,12),jour;
    /// le traitement de la date
    if((mois==1)||(mois==3)||(mois==5)||(mois==7)||(mois==8)||(mois==10)||(mois==12)) jour = nombreAlea(1,31);
    if((mois==4)||(mois==6)||(mois==9)||(mois==11)) jour = nombreAlea(1,30);
    if(mois==2)
    {if (annee % 4 == 0 )
            jour = nombreAlea(1,28);
        else
            jour = nombreAlea(1,29);
    }
    
    /// the format of the date is  jj/mm/aaaa
    signed char Date[20];
    signed char jour_c[3],mois_c[3],annee_c[6];
    itoa(jour,jour_c,10);
    itoa(mois,mois_c,10);
    itoa(annee,annee_c,10);
    Date[0]=jour_c[0];
    Date[1]=jour_c[1];Date[2]='/';
    Date[3]=mois_c[0];Date[4]=mois_c[1];Date[5]='/';
    Date[6]=annee_c[0];Date[7]=annee_c[1];Date[8]=annee_c[2];Date[9]=annee_c[3];Date[10]='\0';
    printf("%s",Date); 
    
    return 0 ;
}
```

i want to generate a birthday day randomly , but the problem is that sometimes i get the half of the date , and smetimes i get only 2 caracters , and i don't understand where s the problem , any help !

Comment: Which `printf` are you talking about? You have lots of prints. Which prints correct result and which doesn't? What do you get if you replace the random values with fixed values where you know the expected output?

Comment: If you want to put the date in a string, why don't you use `sprintf()` instead of all those array assignments?

Comment: Don't combine multiple statements into one line. Don't write complex expressions. Those two things will make it much easier to *debug* your program when problems happens. And for testing and debugging, use fixed values instead of random values.

Comment: The problem is that `jour_c` will only be 1 digit for days between 1 and 9, so `jour_c[1]` will be the null terminator, not the second digit.

Comment: Does your problem happen if you have single digit numbers in your output? You do not detect if you need to copy 1 or 2 digits to the output string. That would not matter if you used `sprintf` as mentioned above

Comment: Aside: the February days per month is wrong way round.

Comment: And also doesn't handle the special cases for century years.

Comment: Side note: Your code would be easier for other people to understand if you used English variable and function names, instead of French ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar's comment, you can't assume that `jour_c` and `mois_c` are one-character strings. Use

```c
Date[0] = '\0';  // or you can initialize it as signed char Date[20] = {0};
strcat(Date, jour_c);
strcat(Date, "/");
strcat(Date, mois_c);
strcat(Date, "/");
strcat(Date, annee_c);
```

instead of

```c
Date[0]=jour_c[0];
Date[1]=jour_c[1];Date[2]='/';
Date[3]=mois_c[0];Date[4]=mois_c[1];Date[5]='/';
Date[6]=annee_c[0];Date[7]=annee_c[1];Date[8]=annee_c[2];Date[9]=annee_c[3];Date[10]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that `jour_c` will only be 1 digit for days between 1 and 9, so `jour_c[1]` will be the null terminator, not the second digit.

– Barmar